# Android studio: How can I store Path coordinates on a different file like a JSON or a text file and then load it on an activity or a fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a map for my school project, it's a group project yet I am the only one who's coding because my classmate don't even have the basic foundations for programming.

I am creating a campus map and it has a functionality that should be able to open a building and see each floor. Now, I have made the Main campus map and also able to put the Floors of the building on our campus.

I am using an ImageView for the floorplans and I'm using the floorplan that the teacher gave me as the src of the ImageView. I'm going to add a search function to be able for the user to search the floors but how? My plan is to use path to trace every rooms with a PATH but shouldn't I need to store the coordinates in a separate file so that the search functionality can use the coords? and also I might also include a scheduler that will highlight the rooms if it is in his schedule. Can I ask tips from the esteemed programmers of stackoverflow?

I tried chatgpt for help but I just can't seem to make it work.

Comment: You can use a file to store your building with their locations and floors as json. The building would contain a jsonarray of the floors and every floor would have a jsonarray of rooms. The rooms would be stored with their locations. You would also have a json file with the classes the user has. That would consist of a jsonarray of classes and each class has its location and time.

Comment: I think I have an idea now thank you for the help